# Socket has timed out

Tags: sockets, performance-testing

We are trying to access our web-app (through web server, IHS). When we use http we are fine ;**https** protocol is working as it submits the requests, however we observe Socket Time Out Exception continuously after some requests have been processed. Thereafter the request processing resumes again. We have tested the application with quite large concurrent load using https earlier; but in this case we are not sure why we are getting this error.

Comment: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket operation timed out before it could be completed at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder .java:225) at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder. java:128)

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, this can be due to thousands of different things. I would suggest a layer analysis approach starting off by the Web Server logs, you need to make sure the requests are reaching your web server and what is happening to the ones dictating a time out, you could be facing anything from network latency to a resource bounded host, contention or who knows, it all depends on your application's design.

Start off by checking out the network layer. Maybe if you provide some more information I can help you out.

Also check out http and https time out configurations on your web server.